# contested combat photographs of the Spanish Civil War

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does "contested" here mean "controversial and influential"?

Context:
In the tradition of war photography that Sontag outlines—from the Crimean War and the Sepoy Rebellion of 1857 to the **contested** “combat” photographs of the Spanish Civil War—the Vietnam/ American War holds a special place, since in it photographers no longer staged battle as they had in the past ([Art and Politics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=luS97efEY10C&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=%22contested%20%E2%80%9Ccombat%E2%80%9D%20photographs%20of%20the%20Spanish%20Civil%20War%22&source=bl&ots=GH5uYs9ALw&sig=8g2p6CvgXKZFQWBA0J2OojjEf_c&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22contested%20%E2%80%9Ccombat%E2%80%9D%20photographs%20of%20the%20Spanish%20Civil%20War%22&f=false)).

Comment: Where did you get the definition of "controversial and influential?"  I have never seen that definition for contested.

Comment: @KumaAra I thought It meant "controversial" in a positive manner, that it would bring about the meaning of "influential" as well. something like "the photographs that caused so much argument in the society and therefore were influential photographs". However, it seems that I was wrong and as you have appropriately described, it has a story behind it.

Comment: The notion of "contested" here is related to the ideas "challenged" and "disputed"—that is, there is disagreement (presumably among experts) as to the genuineness or circumstantial reliability of the photographs. If the people contesting the legitimacy of the photographs deserve to be taken seriously—that is, if they aren't just crackpots ignorantly ranting about something—the photographs **are** controversial, but the term _contested_ merely indicates that the objective legitimacy and proper place of the photographs in the historical record is currently in dispute.

Answer (score 1):

The quotation marks around combat are used to imply that while the photographs were said to be from combat, this is not necessarily true.  [In modern times, quotation marks have started to be used to imply that something is sarcastic or not true.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_quotes)  Usually this is done with your hands when speaking, but this author is using it in written form.

We can use the implication from the quotation marks to understand the correct meaning of contested.  And that meaning is:

> [to call into question](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contested)

or

> [causing dispute or argument](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/contested)

With a little research, [I found an article about the photo in question](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/08/18/arts/design/18capa.html), Robert Capa's "Falling Solider" and possibly others from his book "Heart of Spain: Robert Capa's Photographs of the Spanish Civil War."

So taken all together, the meaning is that many people have called into question the authenticity of the combat photos.  As the article says, some people now think the photos were staged and not from combat.

Comment: Yes, it seems that you are right. I had not heard of it before. Very interesting. Thank you so much for putting time and searching about it.